# What is the correct way to change EntityManager serviceName?

Tags: breeze

We have a need to change the URL of an EntityManager after it is instantiated but before it's used to make any queries... Down below is the code we are using... Is this the correct way??? After some research I ran into a few places that talk about a "setProperties" method that should perhaps be used for this purpose... But then I looked at the Breeze code and it says this method is obsolete... Is the below fine???? Thank you

```
configure(serviceUrl: string) {
            this._entityManager.serviceName = this._entityManager.dataService.serviceName = serviceUrl;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the release notes, setProperties is only deprecated in Breeze.Sharp. setProperties on the EntityManager in BreezeJS is still valid:

```
manager.setProperties({
    serviceName: serviceUrl
});
```

http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_setProperties